# Philosophy of Financial Risk

Tags: risk, risk-management, risk-models

Do you think that there exists a framework on that you can build risk measures? 
What are the necessary and desirable properties of a risk measure? (necessary means compulsory and desirable means more than necessary).

Comment: You can search for the coherent risk measures. Of particular interest is the property of subadditivity, which has enhanced a great debate on whether VaR is appropriate and so on.